# Ipython notebook 3 disables seaborn settings

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I just upgraded to IPython Notebook version 3.0 and it's disabling the formatting for seaborn. Here's some sample code that replicates the problem

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

%matplotlib inline

data = np.random.randn(100)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (11,8.5))
ax.plot(data)
```

This code works just fine in IPython Notebook V2.4.1 (see http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/anonymous/71733c24a68ee464ca40), but in IPython Notebook v3.0, the axes become invisible (see http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/anonymous/7525146b07709206908c).

Strangely, in V3, when I switch the order of the seaborn import and the matplotlib inline magic, the plot renders normally the first time I run, then if I re-run, the axes and gridlines disappear. So it seems to have something to do with the inline magic disabling seaborn properties.

Any workarounds, other than not re-executing my imports after the first time?

Comment: It's a known issue: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7964. It's not really IPython "disabling" seaborn, but just setting different and conflicting matplotlob parameters for the Axes background.

Comment: Typing "seaborn.set_style('darkgrid')" after the inline magic fixes it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @ollerend. That fixed it for me. You may want to make your answer a full reply so that OP can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iPython Notebook 3.0, add:

```
seaborn.set_style('darkgrid')
```

to restore Seaborn default color schemes.